# Mongoose js batch find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose 3.8. I need to fetch 100 documents, execute the callback function then fetch next 100 documents and do the same thing.

I thought `.batchSize()` would do the same thing, but I'm getting all the data at once.

Do I have to use `limit` or `offset`? If yes, can someone give a proper example to do it?

If it can be done with `batchSize`, why is it not working for me?

```
MySchema.find({}).batchSize(20).exec(function(err,docs)
{
    console.log(docs.length)
});
```

I thought it would print 20 each time, but its printing whole count.

Answer (score 3):

This [link](https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/) has the information you need.
You can do this,

```
var pagesize=100;
MySchema.find().skip(pagesize*(n-1)).limit(pagesize);
```

where n is the parameter you receive in the request, which is the page number client wants to receive.

Comment: No, I dont need paging, I wont have the page number info. All I want to do is, keep on reading data part by part and process it. My processing gets too heavy if there are lot of records.

Answer (score 2):

[Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/) says:

> In most cases, modifying the batch size will not affect the user or the application, as the mongo shell and most drivers return results as if MongoDB returned a single batch.

You may want to take a look at [streams](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/querystream.html) and perhaps try to accumulate subresults:

```
var stream = Dummy.find({}).stream();
stream.on('data', function (dummy) {
  callback(dummy);
})
```